# Accessing query SUM inside a while loop

Tags: php, sql

I currently have this code:

```
$query = query("SELECT SUM(ER_read) 
                FROM tblEread 
                WHERE ER_ID='$sensor' 
                  AND MONTH(ER_date) = '$thisMonth2[1]' 
                  AND YEAR(ER_date) = '$thisMonth2[0]' 
                GROUP BY ER_ID");
while($data = fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $return[0]['data'][] = Array(1,$data['SUM(ER_read)']);  
}
```

which I'm using to try and add all of the `ER_read` results together and then store it in an array. My problem is that the array isn't displaying the sum of the `ER_read`, and if I echo the array it only displays the number one and misses out the `SUM` section completely..

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: could you provide an example of the output?

Comment: I've figured it out - if I put 'SUM(ER_read) as total' and then call $data['total'] instead then it works fine. The tutorial I was reading didnt show it using the 'as' though.

Comment: i would also suggest giving alias to your SUM function. `SELECT SUM(ER_read) as theSum FROM tblEread..` and retreive it like `$data['theSum']` to make it easier.

Comment: This looks like it is PHP and nothing but. If so, perhaps remove javascript jquery and json tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want to just push the SUM in data and keep it as array for each row then this will work:

```
$return[0]['data'][] = $data['SUM(ER_read)'];
```

If you wanted the array to start with 1 as index and not 0, you would do:

```
$return[0]['data'][] = array(1 => $data['SUM(ER_read)']);
```